# Python, how to move an if statement outside of a for loop without duplicating the loop

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I can write my function two ways.

```
def output_ip_hist(target, final, stats, table_name, bulk_qty, type = "sql"):
    if(type == "sql"):
        field_names = ",".join(get_field_names(final, table_name))
        count = 0
        stats[table_name] = 0
        values = []
        for comp_name, row in final.items():
            for ip_address, sub_row in row.items():
                for index, ip_hist in enumerate(sub_row):
                    hist_item = ip_hist.replace('"', "'")
                    values.append('("' + comp_name + '", "' + ip_address + '", ' + str(index) + ',"' + hist_item + '")')
                    count += 1
                    if(count == bulk_qty):
                        insert_sql_many(target, count, table_name, field_names, values, stats)
                        count = 0
                        values = []
        if(count != 0):
            insert_sql_many(target, count, table_name, field_names, values, stats)
    elif(type == "csv"):
        for comp_name, row in final.items():
            for ip_address, sub_row in row.items():
                for index, ip_hist in enumerate(sub_row):
                    insert_csv(target, { "computer_name": comp_name, "id": str(index), "ip_address": ip_address, "hist_item": ip_hist.replace('"', "'") }, stats, table_name)
```

This is the first way. The disadvantage of this way is that the loop is written twice creating some duplication.

The second way would be to move the outer most if statements inside the loop so that the loop is only completed once, but the disadvantage of this is that the if statement gets executed on every single loop, slowing down the loop which may be looping thru 4 million records.

I am wondering if it is possible to get the best of both worlds, reduce repetition and keep the loop as fast as humanly possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could define two functions : `process_sql` and `process_csv`. Depending on `data_type`, you can set `process_data` to be the first function or the second.

Inside the loops, you can use `process_data` :

```
def process_sql(a,b):
    print "SQL"
    return a-b

def process_csv(a,b):
    print "CSV"
    return a+b

data_type = "CSV"

if data_type == "CSV":
    process_data = process_csv
else:
    process_data = process_sql

for a in range(3):
    for b in range(3):
        print process_data(a,b)
#   CSV 
#   0
#   CSV
#   1
#   CSV
#   2
#   CSV
#   1
#   CSV
#   2
#   CSV
#   3
#   CSV
#   2
#   CSV
#   3
#   CSV
#   4
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try writing a generator to produce the stream of values from your nested loops. This also lets you use `itertools.islice` to simplify your SQL batch code.

```
def my_generator(final):
    for comp_name, row in final.items():
        for ip_address, sub_row in row.items():
            for index, ip_hist in enumerate(sub_row):
               yield comp_name, ip_address, index, ip_hist.replace('"', "'")

def output_ip_hist(target, final, stats, table_name, bulk_qty, type = "sql"):
    items = my_generator(final)
    if type == "sql":
        field_names = ",".join(get_field_names(final, table_name))
        stats[table_name] = 0
        while True:
            values = ['("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")' % i for i in islice(items, bulk_qty)]
            if not values:
                break                
            insert_sql_many(target, len(values), table_name, field_names, values, stats)
    elif type == "csv":
        for comp_name, ip_address, index, hist_item in items:
            blob = {
                "computer_name": comp_name,
                "id": str(index),
                "ip_address": ip_address,
                "hist_item": hist_item
            }
            insert_csv(target, blob, stats, table_name)
```

It is somewhat of an antipattern, though, to merge what is effectively two different functions into a single function that wraps an `if` statment.

```
def output_ip_hist_sql(target, final, stats, table_name, bulk_qty):
    field_names = ",".join(get_field_names(final, table_name))
    stats[table_name] = 0

    items = my_generator(final)
    while True:
        values = ['("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")' % i for i in islice(items, bulk_qty)]
        if not values:
            break                
        insert_sql_many(target, len(values), table_name, field_names, values, stats)

def output_ip_hist_csv(target, final, stats, table_name):
    items = my_generator(final)
    for comp_name, ip_address, index, hist_item in items:
        blob = {
            "computer_name": comp_name,
            "id": str(index),
            "ip_address": ip_address,
            "hist_item": hist_item
        }
        insert_csv(target, blob, stats, table_name)
```